# Hydraulic Disc Brakes Not Locking Up

Tags: maintenance, shimano, safety, disc-brake, parts

So as the title says my disc brakes are not locking up. They are gripping but not locking. My older brakes were leaking and i changed them with Shimano Deore BL-M596. I have searched online and found some things about pads. I checked for any contamination on my pads and my rotor but they seem to be fine. No oil or anything. How do i get them to lock? Thanks!

Comment: What have you done? Did you bleed them properly?

Comment: Probably need to be bled, did you cut or shorten the lines when installing the new brakes? If so have you given proper time for them to be broken in aka bed in?

Comment: You can't really check for disc contamination, even a very fine film will do you pads in, you presume the discs are contaminated until cleaned. If the discs were contaminated and not cleaned, chances are the pads on the new brakes are now contaminated and will need cleaning or replacing. 
Suggest going though the installation methodically as it could be anything - caliper alignment, contamination, bleeding (sometimes required ex-factory), or it might just be the pads need bedding in.

Comment: They are bled by the factory so i just attached them to my bike. I didnt cut or shortened the cables because they are perfect fit. Maybe they just need to bed in.

Comment: They might need bleeding like mattnz said. I will try bleeding them and post an update.

Answer (score 2):

New brakes need to be "bed-in" (not bled), with their rotors: Get up to speed, then drag the brake for 5-6 seconds (builds up heat) and then increase lever pressure until the bike stops. Do this about 10 times.

More on bedding-in brakes here:
http://www.bikeradar.com/us/gear/article/how-to-bed-in-disc-brake-pads-31337/

Comment: From what I've read from SRAM it's not a good idea to complete stop because the "bed" wont be even across the rotor.